# How to pass multiple views as parameters in BindingAdapter in Data binding android?

Tags: android, data-binding

I have one relative layout and one ImageView. I want to set visibility based on Image loading like if image loads successfully then imageview is visible and if some error occurs relative layout is visible. How can I manage this scenario in data binding using BindingAdapter ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear so I don't know if it will help you.
These are steps to implement

1: Create parameters in BindingAdapter.kt

```
@BindingAdapter("showLoading")
fun View.showLoading(loading: Boolean) {
    if (loading) {
        visible()
    } else {
        gone()
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("showError")
fun View.showError(error: Boolean) {
    if (error) {
        visible()
    } else {
        gone()
    }
}


fun View.gone() {
    this.visibility = View.GONE
}

fun View.visible() {
    this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

2: Use parameters [app:showLoading="@{viewModel.showLoading}"] and [app:showError="@{viewModel.showError}"] created in file XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.xxx.xxx.MainViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EAEAE2"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ShowLoading" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:showLoading="@{viewModel.showLoading}" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewError"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:showError="@{viewModel.showError}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

3: Create showError and showLoading variables in Viewmodel.
And assign the viewModel variable to the binding.

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val showError: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    val showLoading: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    
    init {
        showError.postValue(false)
        showLoading.postValue(true)
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel = MainViewModel()
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        initViews()
    }

    private fun initViews() {
        binding.btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.showError.postValue(true)
            viewModel.showLoading.postValue(false)
        }
    }
}
```